# Entity Framework (one to one mapping) fetches dependency model as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

**Table dbo.Users:**
    UserId,
    UserName,
    Email,
    ...

**Table dbo.Client:**
    UserID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ...

**Models:**

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Client
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My DBContents contains:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.UserId)
                    .HasRequired(x => x.Client).WithRequiredPrincipal();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.UserId)
                    .ToTable("Client");
}
```

In result I have user model with null client.
But if I fetch Client by same UserId I'd see that model was filled.

Whats wrong?

**Edited:**

```
public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you defined your User's client property correctly:

```
public virtual Client UserClient { get; set; }
```

Doing this would allow EF to generate a dynamic proxy - subclass your User class at run time and insert code to support lazy loading for the client property. The Client property would only be populated when it is requested but will appear as if it's always been there - verify this by profiling your data source and checking 2 separate queries are emitted.

You can also check you have lazy loading switched on, inside your DBContext subclass' constructor. If this is missing it will be true by default.

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Failing this how are you accessing the DBContext, what code are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Of course its better to make LazyLoadings disabled and you yourself handle it.

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

And when you are fetching users you should write:

```
context.Users.Include("UserClient").ToList();
```

And you should have the correct property too:

```
public virtual Client UserClient { get; set; }
```